# how to store data from firebase into arraylist in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

//entityList is my arraylist of type HomeScreenEntity(two string data members)

**entityList is unable to retain its data outside the addOnSuccessListner? why??**

```
val docRef = database.collection("DepartmentImages_C").document("DepartmentImages_C")

    docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")

                entityList.add(HomeScreenEntity(document["ComputerDepartment"].toString(),"ComputerDepartment"))
                entityList.add(HomeScreenEntity(document["LawDepartment"].toString(),"LawDepartment"))
                entityList.add(HomeScreenEntity(document["LiteratureDepartment"].toString(),"LiteratureDepartment"))
                entityList.add(HomeScreenEntity(document["ScienceDepartment"].toString(),"ScienceDepartment"))

                Toast.makeText(application.applicationContext,entityList[0].departmentName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() // this one is working fine

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
        }
    Toast.makeText(application.applicationContext,entityList[0].departmentName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  // this toast message is giving me index out of bound error
}
```

entityList is unable to retain its data outside the addOnSuccessListner? why??*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docRef.get() is an asynchronous function. So when docRef.get() is working in background thread, toast will get executed but will not show what you want because entityList is not updated yet.

Comment: I'am having the same problem. What is the solution? How can we store the document data inside entityList?